# Scope variable in Directive Link is not updated to when Directive Controller reads it using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the my code

```
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/static/myTemplate.html',
        scope: {
        },
        controller: ["$scope", controllerFunc],
        controllerAs: 'multiCheckboxCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        link: linkFunc,

    };

    return directive;


    function controllerFunc($scope) {

        // $watch List

        /**
         * Event handler for searchText change
         */
        $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
            return $scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value;
        }), function (newVal) {
            if (newVal !== undefined && newVal !== "") {
                console.log(newVal);
                console.log("I am here");
            }
        });


    }

    function linkFunc(scope, element, attr){

        // Detect Element Click Logic
        scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere = {value: false};

        $document.on('click', function(){
            scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = false;
            console.log(scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere);
        });

        element.on('click', function(){
            event.stopPropagation();
            scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = true;
            console.log(scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere);
        });
        // End Detect Element Click Logic

    }
```

The linkFunc basically determines if the directive element is clicked or not.

I verified that whenever the directive element is clicked it consoles true, and when any element outside directive element is clicked it consoles false.

However it seems like my `$watch` in the controller is not catching the change.

Can anyone show me what is going wrong

Thanks

Comment: Try add to your event listener functions following `scope.$apply()`.  Like this `$document.on('click', function(){
            scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = false;
            console.log(scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere);  scope.$apply()
        })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular not know that there was a change object properties in event listener.

As [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)  say:

> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser `DOM events`, `setTimeout`, `XHR` or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/zh7asgxu/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
   
  })
  .directive('clickDirective', function() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>click me</div>',
      scope: {},
      controller: ["$scope", controllerFunc],
      controllerAs: 'multiCheckboxCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      link: linkFunc,

    };

    return directive;


    function controllerFunc($scope) {

      // $watch List

      /**
       * Event handler for searchText change
       */
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value;
      }, function(newVal) {
        if (newVal !== undefined && newVal !== "") {
          console.log(newVal);
          console.log("I am here");
        }
      });


    }

    function linkFunc(scope, element, attr) {

      // Detect Element Click Logic
      scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere = {
        value: false
      };

      angular.element(document).on('click', function() {
        scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = false;
        console.log(scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere);
        scope.$apply();
      });

      element.on('click', function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = true;
        console.log(scope.multiCheckboxCtrl.clickedElsewhere);
        scope.$apply();
      });
      // End Detect Element Click Logic

    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController" id="ExampleController">
    <click-directive></click-directive>
    <div>
       click elsewhere
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```